# Jquery Not being able to disable event

Tags: javascript, jquery

First Question here, i have tried quite a few ways now but still cant get it to do what i want.
This is my Current code:

```
    $('#viewPortButtonForth').click(function()
    {
        state++;
        switcher();
        $('#viewPortButtonForth').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#viewPortButtonForth').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
```

Better description:

I want to disable the .click event after it was clicked, just to enable it again after a second.

`<div id="viewPortButtonForth">
<img src="stuff/back_and_forth.png">
</div>`

Basically what i want is:

```
    $('#viewPortButtonForth').click(function()
    {
        state++;
        switcher();
        disable the click event on itself
        wait 1000ms
        enable the click event again
    });
```

Comment: you cann0t disable a container..!

Comment: What is #viewPortButtonForth ?

Comment: post your html please

Comment: i dont see any html, only javascript, and you cannot disable a div. what exactly do you intend to happen?

Comment: so i updated what i want i hope its more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
function test()
{
    state++;
    switcher();
    $(this).off("click");
    setTimeout(function(){  $(this).on('click',test) },1000);
}

$('#viewPortButtonForth').on('click',test);
```